# Error generating chart: Collection query aborted after accumulating over 5000 elements

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, image-encoding

I have problem with generating charts in GEE. I am trying to calculate NDVI for more than 100 Shapefiles (`FeatureCollection`) and export the results to a chart and CSV file. I got an error:

> Error generating chart: Collection query aborted after accumulating over 5000 elements

How can I revise my code to avoid this error?

```js
// Define a geometry.
var Akdarya = ee.FeatureCollection("users/xodjayevshovkat/Akdarya_GEE_35");

// Make the geometry a feature collection.

// Import S2 image collection.
var S2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
  // Filter collection.
  .filterDate('2018-01-01','2018-12-31')
  .filterBounds(Akdarya)
  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 20));

// Define a cloud masking function.
var maskcloud1 = function(image) {
  var QA60 = image.select(['QA60']);
  return image.updateMask(QA60.lt(1));
};

// Define an index function (return only NDVI).
var NDVI = function(image) {
  return image.expression(
    '(NIR - RED) / (NIR + RED)', 
    {
      'NIR': image.select('B8'), 
      'RED': image.select('B4'), 
    }).rename('NDVI').copyProperties(image, image.propertyNames());
};

// Apply the cloud mask function.
var NDVIcol = S2.map(maskcloud1)
 // Apply the NDVI transformation.
 .map(NDVI);

// Calculate the per-pixel median NDRE for all images in collection.
var NDVImed = NDVIcol.median();

// Define vis params.
var NDVIvis = {
  palette: ['#d73027', '#f46d43', '#fdae61', '#fee08b', '#d9ef8b', '#a6d96a'],
  min: -0.5,
  max: 0.9};

// Plot a time series of 
var plotNDVI = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
  imageCollection:NDVIcol,
  regions: Akdarya,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  //scale: 1000,
  xProperty: 'system:time_start',
  seriesProperty: 'system:index'})
  .setChartType('LineChart').setOptions({
    title: 'NDVI Akdarya 2018',
    hAxis: {title: 'Date'},
    vAxis: {title: 'NDVI'},
});

// Display the results.
print(plotNDVI);
Map.addLayer(NDVImed.clipToCollection(Akdarya), NDVIvis, 'NDVI');
```

Comment: You have to share your 'users/xodjayevshovkat/Akdarya_GEE_35' asset, so this can be tested.

Comment: Perhaps you could try to use weekly or monthly aggregates when you're charting.

Comment: https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/xodjayevshovkat/Akdarya_GEE

Comment: https://code.earthengine.google.com/2489456a0c8ac9dc53c4b4d048605464

Comment: The asset is still not shared. To share an asset, you click on the asset in the left-hand-side "Assets" tab, click "Share", check the "Anyone can read" box, finally click "Done".

Comment: Thank you for detailed instruction how to share. Could you please check my share. I appreciate your support in this matter. Thank you very much.

Comment: 'users/xodjayevshovkat/Akdarya_GEE_35' is still not accessible by me

Comment: Could you please check again. If is still not accessible for you please send me your gmail address. Sorry for my a lot of mistakes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your image collection contains 493 images, and your feature collection contains 35 features. Combining these, you end up with over 17,000 elements. There’s a limit of 5,000. This means, you cannot chart more than 10 regions at a time (4,930 elements).

You could create multiple charts, each with no more than 10 regions in each. Perhaps even have a separate chart for each region?

```
var regions = Akdarya.toList(Akdarya.size())
var regionCount = Akdarya.size().evaluate(function (count) {
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    var plotNDVI = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
      imageCollection:NDVIcol,
      regions: ee.FeatureCollection([ee.Feature(regions.get(i))]),
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
      xProperty: 'system:time_start',
      seriesProperty: 'Farmers'})
      .setChartType('LineChart').setOptions({
        title: 'NDVI Akdarya 2018',
        hAxis: {title: 'Date'},
        vAxis: {title: 'NDVI'},
    });
    print(plotNDVI);    
  }
})
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/4889ba40bea61d5c189b80ab247f53db