# Exporting many charts to Google Drive using Google Earth Engine JavaScript API

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am extracting mean NDVI over many years for each polygon in a shapefile, masked by each landcover within each polygon.

I want each chart/CSV to be stored in my Google Drive. Ideally for each masked set of files, the CSV filenames should be appended by the mask name so I can keep track.

Here's the code so far:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/3001abdda6eb3c3c51774535f5586e32

```
// Import the example feature collection           
print(Catchments);
// Import the NLCD collection.
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('USGS/NLCD_RELEASES/2019_REL/NLCD');

// The collection contains images for multiple years and regions in the USA.
print('Products:', dataset.aggregate_array('system:index'));

// Filter the collection to the 2019 product.
var nlcd2019 = dataset.filter(ee.Filter.eq('system:index', '2019')).first();

// Each product has multiple bands for describing aspects of land cover.
print('Bands:', nlcd2019.bandNames());

// Select the land cover band.
var landcover = nlcd2019.select('landcover');

// Create a binary mask.
var urbanmask = landcover.expression("b('landcover') == 41 || b('landcover') == 42 || b('landcover') == 44");
// Update the composite mask with the water mask.
var watermask = landcover.eq(11);//all pixels not 11 are masked
var forestmask = landcover.expression("b('landcover') == 41 || b('landcover') == 42 || b('landcover') == 44");
var nonforestmask = landcover.expression("b('landcover') == 51 || b('landcover') == 52 || \
                    b('landcover') == 71 || b('landcover') == 72 || b('landcover') == 73 || \
                    b('landcover') == 74 || b('landcover') == 90 || b('landcover') == 95");
var barrenmask = landcover.expression("b('landcover') == 12 || b('landcover') == 31");
var cultivatedmask = landcover.expression("b('landcover') == 81 || b('landcover') == 82");
var devopenspacemask = landcover.expression("b('landcover') == 21");
var devlowintmask = landcover.expression("b('landcover') == 22");
var devmedintmask = landcover.expression("b('landcover') == 23");
var devhighintmask = landcover.expression("b('landcover') == 24");
// Update the mask with the appropriate mask.
var maskedLandcover = landcover.updateMask(forestmask);
//var maskedLandcover = landcover.updateMask(mask);
    
// Load MODIS vegetation indices data and subset a decade of images.
var vegIndices = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD13A1')
                 .filter(ee.Filter.date('2010-01-01', '2022-09-30'))
                 .select(['NDVI', 'EVI']);
print(vegIndices)
// create masked image collection
//var maskedvegIndices = vegIndices.updateMask(maskedLandcover);
    var maskedvegIndices = vegIndices.map(function (image) {
 return image.updateMask(maskedLandcover);
});


// Subset catchments to only one polygon
var onecatch=ee.FeatureCollection("projects/ee-vishal-mehta/assets/WEAPCatchment")
              .filter(ee.Filter.eq('Name','P508_Yuba_I_ENGLB'));
    //Subset catchment to about 20 catchments starting with the string P508
var P508=ee.FeatureCollection("projects/ee-vishal-mehta/assets/WEAPCatchment")
              .filter(ee.Filter.stringContains('Name','P508_Yuba'));                  
// "Collection query aborted after accumulating over 5000 elements."
// Modified per polygon using solution here:
// https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/348157/error-generating-chart-collection-query-aborted-after-accumulating-over-5000-el
    var regions = Catchments.toList(Catchments.size())
    var regionCount = Catchments.size().evaluate(function (count) {
       for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        var plotNDVI = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
          imageCollection:maskedvegIndices,
          regions: ee.FeatureCollection([ee.Feature(regions.get(i))]),
  band:'EVI',
          reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
          xProperty: 'system:time_start',
          seriesProperty: 'Name'})
          .setChartType('LineChart').setOptions({
            title: i,
            hAxis: {title: 'Date'},
            vAxis: {title: 'EVI'},
    });
        print(plotNDVI);    
  }
})

    //Map.addLayer(table,"","catchments");
    Map.addLayer(Catchments,"","Catchments");
    Map.setCenter(-120.84497, 39.01918, 8);
    Map.style().set('cursor', 'crosshair');
```

Comment: What happens when you run the code that you’ve presented?  You’ve told us what you want to do but not where you’re stuck with your code attempts.

Comment: when i run the code, each chart (1 for each of the 276 polygons in the shapefile) appears in the console. I want to automate the export of the data for each chart to google drive. I need to use that data in a hydrologic model.

Answer (score 0):

There is no automated/automatable mechanism for saving a chart.  Your best bet is to export the collections as CSV files and use an external charting tool (maybe Google Sheets)

Comment: How do I modify this script to export the collections as CSV's?

Comment: Instead of doing a seriesByRegion chart, you just do the equivalent reduceRegions by mapping over the collection and Export of those results.